# How do edit a .shp file geometry manually?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

In the program that I've designed, I am loading a .shp file with custom .dbf attributes. Once a week the national institute releases an updated database in the form of a .shp file. Because my .shp includes custom .dbf attribute fields, I would have to manually find all the newly added objects and import them to my .shp file and then fill out the attribute fields (open attributes table tool).

Is there a method to edit a .shp file geometry in a "text" editor, similar to how you can edit the attribute table in QGIS?

I've managed to convert the .shp and .dbf file to SQL geometry table, edit the fields, but I am unable to find a method to convert SQL geometry back to a .shp/.dbf file.

Comment: Do you really mean the .shp file of a shapefile? in a text editor?  You've tagged qgis, but you don't mention qgis at all in the question, how is it relevant?

Comment: @nmtoken becuse I am using QGIS tool to edit the attribute table, which is essentially a glorified text editor. I was wondering if there is a QGIS tool that would allow me to edit the shapes in a text form. Perhaps would it be possible to link the sql geometry to QGIS then export it in a shp/dbf file?

Comment: By editing the shape you mean editing the geometry ? Anyway you could export your shapefile to csv including the geometry as wkt, this way everything is editable in a text editor and could be converted back as shapefile if needed